# Magneto 2: How to remove duplicate sku with images in each rows of CSV

Tags: magento2, custom, script

I am using magento2x. I need to create custom script for removing duplicate sku's with images  with multiple entries of sku's in each rows of csv.if anyone know reply me.

Answer (score 0):

I find out solutions:

```
<?php 
$csvFile = file('remove_duplicates.csv');
$data = [];
foreach($csvFileas$line){
   $data[ = str_getcsv($line);
      unset($data[0]);
}


foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
$skuArray[]   = $value[0];
$mediaImgs[$value[0]][] = $value[1];

}
$uniqueSkus = array_unique($skuArray);
$uniqueSkus = array_values($uniqueSkus);


$fp = fopen("remove_duplicate_imgs.csv","w");
fputcsv($fp, array('sku', 'M1 Media Images'));

foreach ($mediaImgs as $skuArray => $imgs) {
$data = array();
$imagesImploaded = implode(",", $imgs);

$data[] = $skuArray;
$data[] = $imagesImploaded;
fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = remove_duplicate_imgs.csv");
  readfile("remove_duplicate_imgs.csv");
fclose($fp);
```